# Returning 0-length arrays from fortran to python using f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I'm using `f2py` to generate a wrapper for an MPI-based library written in fortran. Due to the array partitioning scheme I am using it is possible for a process to have a local array with a length of 0, given enough MPI processes. This triggers the following error on the Cray system to which I have access:

```
ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- 
must have defined dimensions but got (0,)
```

I do not receive the same error on my desktop. This is probably related to the versions of python and numpy I have installed. On my desktop they are numpy version 1.16.4 and python 2.7.15+ and on the cluster they are numpy 1.13.3 and python 2.7.14. As I cannot upgrade the packages on the cluster, I am wondering if a simple workaround exists. The following code reproduces the error:

File 'fortran_sub.f90':

```
subroutine sub(a_size, a)                                                       
                                                                            
    integer, intent(in) :: a_size                                               
    real, dimension(a_size), intent(out) :: a                                   
                                                                          
    if (size(a) > 0) then                                                       
        a = size(a)                                                             
    endif                                                                       
                                                                              
end subroutine sub
```

Wrapped and compiled using f2py as follows:

```
python2 -m numpy.f2py -h --overwrite-signature fortran_sub.pyf -m 
fortran_sub fortran_sub.f90

python2 -m numpy.f2py --f90exec="ftn" -c fortran_sub.pyf -m 
fortran_sub fortran_sub.f90
```

The generated .pyf is:

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module fortran_sub ! in 
    interface  ! in :fortran_sub
        subroutine sub(a_size,a) ! in :fortran_sub:fortran_sub.f90
            integer intent(in) :: a_size
            real dimension(a_size),intent(out),depend(a_size) :: a
        end subroutine sub
     end interface 
end python module fortran_sub

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
! See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
```

Running the following python program 'pytest.py' with python2 pytest.py:

```
import fortran_sub

a = fortran_sub.sub(2)
print(a)

a = fortran_sub.sub(1)
print(a)

a = fortran_sub.sub(0)
print(a)
```

I obtain the following output:

```
[ 2.  2.]
[ 1.]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 11, in <module>
   a = fortran_sub.sub(0)
ValueError: failed to create intent(cache|hide)|optional array-- must have defined dimensions but got (0,)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not used f2py for a long time, ever since I got to know `ctypes` for Python-Fortran interface. Here is a solution based on `ctypes` that can also handle zero-sized arrays (which should technically also work with MPI),

```
module sub_mod
contains
    subroutine sub(a_size, a) bind(C,name="sub")
        !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: sub
        use iso_c_binding, only: c_size_t, c_double
        integer(c_size_t), intent(in) :: a_size
        real(c_double), intent(inout) :: a(a_size)
        if (size(a) > 0) then
            a = size(a)
        endif
    end subroutine sub
end module sub_mod
```

compile it with Intel or (other compilers) to create DLL library,

```
ifort /dll main.f90
```

with an output message like the following from ifort,

```
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.0.4.245 Build 20190417
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.22.27905.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:main.dll
-dll
-implib:main.lib
main.obj
   Creating library main.lib and object main.exp
```

which can be then called from Python via ctypes like the following,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

# import Fortran DLL
lib = ct.CDLL("main.dll")
lib.sub.restype = None    # define subroutine result type

# define subroutine argument type
lib.sub.argtypes =  [ ct.POINTER(ct.c_size_t)        # a_size
                    , ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)       # a array
                    ]
# all Fortran DLL
for i in [2,1,0]:
    a_size = i
    a = np.zeros(shape=[a_size])
    lib.sub ( ct.byref( ct.c_size_t(a_size) ) # Fortran passes everything around by reference
            , np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes( a ) # pointer to numpy array
            )
    print("a_size = {}, a = {}".format(a_size, a))
```

which gives the following,

```
a_size = 2, a = [2. 2.]
a_size = 1, a = [1.]
a_size = 0, a = []
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Though, ironically I actually switched over from ctypes a couple months back after becoming convinced that f2py was a more efficient way of doing things. I think I will stick to using ctypes in the future, I much prefer knowing exactly what is going on.  For now however, I am hoping that someone has a f2py specific solution.